# R Raster layer of pixels overlapped by shapefile of points

Tags: raster, r

Given a raster layer and a shapefile of points. 
How can I get, in R, a new raster layer of pixel values only where there are the point, while all other raster pixel values are kept as NaN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a more direct way, but I can do it this way....

First a test raster and five test points:

```
> r = raster(matrix(runif(12),3,4))
> pts = st_as_sf(data.frame(x=runif(5),y=runif(5)),coords=1:2)
```

(Note: if you don't know how to read points from a shapefile or rasters from a raster file those Qs can be answered elsewhere)

Now `extract` will get the raster value at each point. But if you add `cell=TRUE` you can also get the raster cell numbers:

```
> extract(r,pts)
[1] 0.1646683 0.1870481 0.4732353 0.8717667 0.4732353
> extract(r,pts,cell=TRUE)
     cells     layer
[1,]     2 0.1646683
[2,]     5 0.1870481
[3,]     8 0.4732353
[4,]    12 0.8717667
[5,]     8 0.4732353
```

in the first column:

```
> extract(r,pts,cell=TRUE)[,1]
[1]  2  5  8 12  8
```

You can use the **negation** of that to set the cells that *aren't* hit by points to NA:

```
> r[][-extract(r,pts,cell=TRUE)[,1]]=NA
```

giving:

```
> plot(r)
> plot(pts, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

If you want to save the original raster, make a copy of that first, eg:

```
> pointRaster <- originalRaster
```

and work on the copy.

There's probably a function that does all this but sometimes its quicker to code from scratch than hunt in the documentation...

Comment: How can I get the number of points falling in each pixel?

Comment: That's a different question! So start a new one! And start it with some code to make sample data (like in my answer).

Comment: a questions if the raster is projected Landsat image as well as the points should it work the same?